# Stop Button Click Event On Directive Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular2-directives, stoppropagation

I built my app with angular 2 and PrimeNG. I try to use directives on button click for checking user authority. Problem is; 
if there is no authority, do not continue button click action. But stopPropagation doesn't stop click event. How to stop process if checkAuth() returns false?

> Blockquote

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[checkAuthOnClick]'
})

export class CheckAuthorizationOnClickDirective {

    user: Observable<User>;
    @Input() allowedClaim: any;
    observer: MutationObserver;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
        this.element = element.nativeElement;
    }

    @Output()
    stop: EventEmitter<Event> = new EventEmitter;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event, $event.target'])
    onClick(event, targetElement) {  
        if (!this.checkAuth()) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            event.cancelBuble = true;
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

            this.stop.emit(event);
        }
    }   

    private checkAuth(): boolean {
        this.user = this.store.select(fromRoot.currentUser);
        if (this.user != undefined && this.allowedClaim != undefined) {
            var hasClaim = false;
            var description;
            this.user.subscribe(x => {
                if (Array.isArray(this.allowedClaim)) { //Gelen/Giden Faturaları görüntüleme yetkileri tümü ve kendisine ait o.ş birden çok olduğu için app.routes'ta array olarak tanımlandı. 
                    for (let i = 0; i < this.allowedClaim.length; i++) {
                        hasClaim = x.hasClaim(this.allowedClaim[i])
                        if (hasClaim)
                            break;
                    }

                    description = this.allowedClaim[0].Description;
                }
                else {
                    hasClaim = x.hasClaim(this.allowedClaim);
                    description = this.allowedClaim.Description;
                }
            });

            if (hasClaim == false) {
                var message = "Bu işlem için yetkiniz yoktur.";
                if (description != undefined) {
                    message = description + ' yetkiniz yoktur.'
                }

                this.store.dispatch(new ui.ToastMessagePushAction({ severity: 'warning', summary: message, detail: '' }));
            }
        }

        return hasClaim;
    }

}
```

Directive usage on html like this;

```
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file-code-o" (click)="createForm()" checkAuthOnClick [allowedClaim]="systemDefinedClaims?.CreateInvoiceDesign"></button>
```

Comment: [This](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/advanced-angular/directives/creating_an_attribute_directive.html) should help.

Comment: Yes, it works thank you so much. But now, i have a problem like this, button click event use this keyword;                                  
   createForm() {
    this.router.navigate(['/ayarlar/fatura-gorsel/olustur']);
  }   but still this key value as directive page.

Answer (score 5):

Binding event by `(click)` and `HostBinding` just means binding two standalone events to your target elements, they will be called at the same time and **won't give effects to each other** which means stop any of them won't stop the other one.

You need to call click event(*currently binding via `(click)`*) manually in your directive's click event binding via `HostBinding`.

```
// transfer click event into directive
@Input('clickEvent') clickEvent;


@HostListener('click', ['$event, $event.target'])
onClick(event, targetElement) {  
    if (!this.checkAuth()) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        this.stop.emit(event);
    } else {
        this.clickEvent();
    }
}
```

See **[sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqjqyn?file=src/app/checkAuth.directive.ts)**.