# Event preventDefault on ion-button click not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-directive, ionic4

I’m using Ionic 4 and I made a directive to prevent clicks on components if some condition applies.

```
  @Directive({
      selector: '[appDisable]'
  })
  export class DisableDirective {

      @Input() ifTruthy: boolean = false;

      @HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickEvent(event: Event): boolean {
      if (this.ifTruthy) {
          console.log('Preventing click');
          console.log('This should prevent further clicks from happening?');
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          return false;
      }

      return true;
      }

      constructor(
      private element: ElementRef,
      protected renderer: Renderer2) {
      }
  }
```

Then on my button:

```
<ion-button appDisable [ifTruthy]="1 === 1" (click)="presentAlert()">Disabled</ion-button>
```

This does not work, it works if I move the click() to an upper element (due to the stopPropagation), I want to know why this does not work.

I made a [stackBlitzz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-event-propagation)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After a long time I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365746/stop-button-click-event-on-directive-angular-2) which solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `event.preventDefault();` in the top of the function. Sometimes it's too late and the software has already done the event.

Comment: if you add a console.log on each method you will see that the @HostListener method executes first, plus there is no race condition in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do stop propagation in event capturing phase to prevent executing the ionic's handler.